# Microsoft QnA maker - Custom message if "no good match found" more than once

Tags: javascript, node.js, azure, botframework, azure-language-understanding

I am building an Azure BOT using node.js that connects to the QNA Maker to serve answers. 
What I would like to do is to be able to treat the cases when for multiple times the bot would send back an answer with no match found.

Maybe not the first time, but if let's say for 3 times in a row the answer is not found, the bot should propose to connect to human operator.

I guess I would need to do while loop, and put a counter . However is not really clear to me how to treat the answers from the QnaMaker.

Do you have some examples, pseudocode?

Thanks!

Comment: This example uses the LUIS service, but similar concepts apply - check out this article: [Transferring chat to a human agent using Microsoft Bot Framework](https://ankitbko.github.io/2017/03/human-handover-bot/)

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/bot-framework/bot-design-pattern-handoff-human

Comment: Check out this video from MS Build conf - [Bot Human Handoff](https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/projects/events/build/2017/bot-human-handoff?playlist=Building-Savvy-Sophisticated-AI)

Comment: Node.js code example - https://github.com/palindromed/Bot-HandOff